# Azure mobile service query using collection contains

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

First of all sorry for the title.

I need to select a list of items from my *Azure Data Service* and I need to select just the items related to other items that I have in a local collection.

If the explanation is not clear, here's the code that I'm using:

```
_result = await _itemTable.Where(item => myCollection.Contains(item.myCollectionItem)).ToCollectionAsync();
```

I'm expecting my query to return all the items which have the `myCollectionItem` property contained in the `myCollection` collection and, since the collection is empty now, I'm expecting `_result` to be empty too.

What happens is that `_results` contains ALL the items in the database.

Now, I know that I can just get the whole table and filter it offline, but I don't think that this is the best way to solve this problem and so I'm asking for your help.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old now, but, what I do in this case is if myCollection is empty you can either avoid issuing this query or add an item to myCollection which you know will not match any of the item.myCollectionItem. Basically, if myCollection is empty, you expect an empty result as you said, so you either avoid issuing the query or mock an list with one item to get an empty result.